# overload indexer style [][] vs [x,y]

Tags: c#, overloading, indexer

I am trying to write a custom overload for the indexer. At the moment i have a 2D array defined as follows:

```
private float[][] Values;
```

Now I want to make an overload for my custom struct like so but this doesn't compile..

```
float this[int x][int y] { get; set; }
```

I saw it is possible to do it in the following way:

```
private float[,] Values;
```

with an overload like so:

```
float this[int x, int y] { get; set; }
```

But i like the `[][]` syntax way better then the `[x, y]` syntax. Is there a way to create the type of overload I am looking for?

Comment: You would have to define a type for `this[int x]` that’s itself indexable. But if your array is actually 2D – i.e. it’s rectangular, not a potentially jagged array of arrays – `[int x, int y]` is much cleaner. Try to live with its looks?

Comment: Maybe I will have to live with the looks.. But could you maybe elaborate a bit on the defining of a type for `this[int x]` I am no pro at c#

Comment: If you want `foo[x][y]` to be possible, `foo[x]` has to be something, and you have to come up with what that something is.

Comment: Cool thanks, probably going for the less fancy style then imo  :)

Comment: Note that `float[][]` and `float[,]` are not just a different look, they are different animals. `float[][]` is an array of arrays - each of the `float[]` arrays returned by the first [] may have a different length (or even be null). OTOH, [,] is a 2-dimensional (rectangular) array of floats.

Answer (score 1):

[DotNetFiddle example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1hChaD)

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using SCG = System.Collections.Generic;

var indexer = new Indexer<float>
{
    Payload = [
        [float.Epsilon, float.Epsilon, float.Epsilon],
        [float.Epsilon, float.Pi, float.Epsilon],
        [float.Epsilon, float.Epsilon, float.Epsilon],
    ]
};
Console.WriteLine(indexer[1][1]); // Output: 3.1415927
Console.WriteLine(indexer[1, 1]); // Output: 3.1415927

public class Indexer<T> {
    public Indexer() => Payload = [[]];
    public SCG.IEnumerable<SCG.IEnumerable<T>> Payload { get; init; }

    public T[] this[int row] {
        get => Payload.ValueAt(row).ToArray();
    }
    public T this[int row, int col] {
        get => this[row].ValueAt(col);
    }
}
internal static class Extension {
    internal static T ValueAt<T>(this SCG.IEnumerable<T> collection, int index)
        => collection.ToArray()[index];
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

The `[int][int]` syntax is not one double-index lookup. Rather, it's actually **two separate single-index operations**.

Therefore, to get the desired behavior you must first define the single `[int]` index behavior so the type of the result value (usually an array or List) **also** has a single `[int]` indexer and can give the desired final value.